# C# which is faster do/while or for?

Tags: c#, refactoring, c#-2.0, benchmarking

I have a C# .NET 2.0 script and I want to know why the following code would be faster than a do while loop of the same kind.

```
private double getStop(double avgPrice, bool longTrading)
    {
        double stopS = 0.0;
        double stopL = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 12)
            {
                stopS = 0.0;
                stopL = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((lines[i] - ((lines[i] - lines[i - 1]) / 2)) < avgPrice && avgPrice < (lines[i + 1] - ((lines[i + 1] - lines[i]) / 2)))
                {
                    if (avgPrice < lines[i])
                    {
                        stopL = (lines[i] - ((lines[i] - lines[i - 1]) / 2));
                        stopS = lines[i];
                    } else {
                        stopL = lines[i];
                        stopS = (lines[i + 1] - ((lines[i + 1] - lines[i]) / 2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (longTrading)
        {
            return stopL;   
        } else {
            return stopS;   
        }   
    }
```

Also, would it be faster just to explicitly state each if statement instead of doing them inside of a for loop?

Being that this was answered so fast, why would this run far slower than the above code?

```
private double getStop(double avgPrice, bool longTrading)
    {
        double stopS = 0.0;
        double stopL = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 12)
            {
                stopS = 0.0;
                stopL = 0.0;
                skip = true;
            }

            if (!skip && (lines[i] - ((lines[i] - lines[i - 1]) / 2)) < avgPrice && avgPrice < (lines[i + 1] - ((lines[i + 1] - lines[i]) / 2)))
                {
                    if (avgPrice < lines[i])
                    {
                        stopL = (lines[i] - ((lines[i] - lines[i - 1]) / 2));
                        stopS = lines[i];
                    } else {
                        stopL = lines[i];
                        stopS = (lines[i + 1] - ((lines[i + 1] - lines[i]) / 2));
                    }
                }
            }
           skip = false;
        }

        if (longTrading)
        {
            return stopL;   
        } else {
            return stopS;   
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be essentially equivalent.  Your 'for' loop gets evaluated as:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 13)
{
   //all other stuff
   i++;
};
```

Comment: +1: In general, I'd expect the compiler or interpreter to convert the `for` sugar to `while`.

Answer (score 4):

The performance difference should be negligible, but the for loop is clearer so I would go with that.

Answer (score 2):

loop variations aren't too much different, it depends on the context and the programming language.

But my opinion is, `for` statement don't **do** until the constaint(s) is/are matched, therefore it *should* be faster than do/while.

Comment: In my world, 0 is always less than 13, and thus the for loop above will always be executed. Besides, isn't a for loop just syntactic sugar for a do-while loop anyway? Am I just missing something in your explanation?

Comment: lc, I don't know how any given language implements `for` or `while` or `do`/`while` behind the scenes, but intuitively it seems that a `for` loop is a specialized `while` loop (not `do`/`while`), and at least in the languages I use, if you pass a `for` loop a boundary parameter that evaluates false on first execution, the loop never runs. Eg. `for(i = 10; i < 9; i++) { /* This never runs */ }`. This is the behavior of a `while` loop.